# Analysis tool for counting memory operations for C++ programs?

Tags: c++, performance-analysis

I need a software tool that can take an arbitrary program (specifically a C++ program) and count the memory operations (loads and stores) made by that program. I understand there are many different performance analysis tools (valgrind, callgrind...) but as far as I can tell they don't have an easy way to count these operations. Other tools use hardware counters to count instructions and such, but I would like something that is hardware-independent (perhaps something that analyzes object code). Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @jitter Linux (centos)